# Django no User with same username in database

Tags: python, django

I'm particularly new to django and still in the learning process.
I have this code where it would have the user input any text into the field and once the user hits the submit button it would grab the text they inputted and look for it in the django database for that item. It's able to do what I want, except when there are no users with that username. I don't know where I would do an if statement, or a work around for that.

```
views.py

from .forms import RequestPasswordResetForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def request_password(request):
    next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
    if request.method == "POST":
        user = request.POST['passUsername']
        users = User.objects.get(username=user)
        form = RequestPasswordResetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Request has been sent! Admin will be with you shortly.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can handle it within the try catch block where `get` method will raise exception (DoesNotExist) if then object is not present in the DB.

```
def request_password(request):
    next = request.POST.get('next', '/')
    try:
        if request.method == "POST":
            username = request.POST['passUsername']
            user = User.objects.get(username=username)
            form = RequestPasswordResetForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, 'Request has been sent! Admin will be with you shortly.')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, 'Invalid Username')
```

Comment: That did not work for me. Gave the same error I've been getting. 
'django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist'

Comment: Sorry Just update the code, the moment I read my answer i realize it will failed and thats why fixed.

Comment: That one worked. Thank You!

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use an if statement alongside the function 'exists()'. It would look something like this:

```
username = request.POST['passUsername']

if (User.objects.exists(username = username):
    user = User.objects.get(username = username)
else:
    # Throw error
```

Also, be careful with your variable naming :)